# How can I delete old translations?

Tags: translation, facebook-opengraph

I have noticed that when I change a word on a new action before submitting it to Facebook, it generates new translations. How can I delete old translations so that I don't need to translate them ?

Thank you,
Zoé

Answer (score 0):

In the translation tool view for your app, go to the “Dashboard”. There on the right side it should have a link saying something like “delete and re-import all strings/literals”.